# I need to display data on top of a RecyclerView after refreshing

Tags: android

I have been practicing on how to display data using recyclerview and CardView and refreshing to display more data, and I have finally gotten it to work. But somehow when I refresh, new data is shown at the bottom of the last data. I am wondering how do you refresh and show it on top of the list?

This is my Card Adapter

```
 @Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.superheroes_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    SuperHero superHero =  Data.get(position);

    final String textx = superHero.getPublisher();
    float ratingss = Float.parseFloat(textx);

    holder.textViewName.setText(superHero.getName());
    holder.textViewPublisher.setText(superHero.getPublisher());
    holder.rate.setRating(ratingss);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Data.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    //Views

     public TextView textViewName;
    public TextView textViewPublisher;
    public RatingBar rate;

    //Initializing Views
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);
        rate = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    }}
```

And this is my Main Activity

```
 private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount) {
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(requestCount),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    parseData(response);
                  }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //If an error occurs that means end of the list has reached
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
}


 private void getData() {
    requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));  requestCount++;
}

private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

        SuperHero superHero = new SuperHero();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {

            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            superHero.setName(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
            superHero.setPublisher(json.getString(Config.TAG_PUBLISHER));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
```

And lastly this is my refresh where I get data

```
 mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Data Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 getData();
        }
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance guys! :D

Comment: Change   listSuperHeroes.add(superHero); to        listSuperHeroes.add(0,superHero);

Comment: @tinysunlight Hey Thanks A lot bro it works. I really mean it thank you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1:

```
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

        SuperHero superHero = new SuperHero();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {

            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            superHero.setName(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
            superHero.setPublisher(json.getString(Config.TAG_PUBLISHER));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         listSuperHeroes.add(0,superHero);
   }
}
```

Method 2:

```
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManger(context ,VERTICAL, true));
```